# 3D wiggle plot for an analytic signal: Heyser corkscrew/spiral

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, visualization, signals-history

Just reading [The Analytic Impulse](http://andrewduncan.net/air/), A. Duncan, 1988, I met the name "Heyser corkscrew" for the first time in my DSP life, for a 3D display of a cisoid or complex exponential $e^{i\omega }$ (often denoted  $\text{cis}\, x$ for "**c**osine plus $i$ **s**ine").

[image: Heyser corkscrew spiral of the cisoid or complex exponential]

The view is mentioned as Euler formula's 3D view in the context of circular polarization:

[image: Euler formula and circular polarization]

This representation is quite common for analytic signals, but this name does not seem standard. Questions are:

1. What is the history of this Heyser name, with a precise reference?
2. What are the (earlier) history and names for this representation  (going back to the Fourier oblique view)?

After @MBaz hints, the term "Heyser spiral" seems a little more common. It is named after [Richard C. Heyser](http://www.aes.org/aeshc/docs/jaes.obit/JAES_V35_5_PG413.pdf), and can be interpreted as a 3D variant of Nyquist plots... Indeed, in  [A Matter Of Frequency: The Nyquist Plot Explained](https://www.prosoundweb.com/topics/sound_reinforcement/the_nyquist_plot/), one can read:

> Dennis Gabor proposed the “analytic signal” which Richard Heyser
>   developed into what has since been named the Heyser Spiral. The
>   Nyquist plot is the “end view” shadow of the complex analytic signal

Comment: A quick search in my university's libary seems to indicate the name is common in the audio field. Even then, there are just a handful of references.

Comment: Heyser seems a common name. What about him and his corkscrew? Any specific reference?

Comment: There are a few patents: https://www.google.com/patents/US8306242 https://www.google.com/patents/US5956411 and this paper, to which I don't have access: http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=11444

Comment: @MBaz "Spruce Moose: A Slightly Bent Horn", what a beautiful name for a paper

Comment: Laurent, I agree, it's one the best I've seen :)

Comment: Maybe you can answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/144268/2206 ?

Comment: @endolith What an excellent idea, to revive past questions. Done!

Comment: @LaurentDuval Well it's my (unanswered) question, and you seem to have found an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at ancient geophysical papers, I have found in [Truncations and phase relationships of sinusoids](http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/jz072i004p01400), Philip L. Jackson, Journal of Geophysical Research, 1967, this "Fourier transform" with "**oblique view**", that seems to predate Heyser corkscrew/spiral.

[image: Fourier oblique view]

Comment: That doesn't actually show the curve though; it shows real and imaginary parts separately

Comment: Indeed. But I provided this picture for the historical part, for others to dig deeper. I never saw the mention of "oblique" view before. I am stuck with Heyser's works which as hidden under the AES paywall for me

Comment: Yeah I don't have AES either.  I've considered it.